# Critque my 320A residential service design

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

We are on the 2020 NEC.

Going to do a new house next year.  The house will have a large attached shop/garage (think 5-6 car in regards to spacing..) as well as a 5000sq/ft cold storage building.   We are in a cold climate, so there will be electric in-floor heat in the concrete of the basement and garage in addition to propane forced air for the house.

I'm intending to use a 320A meter main with a built-in 400A disconnect.   This disconnect has 3 lugs for each hot and 3 for the neutral.

I will run parallel 4/0 4/0 2/0 AL to the POCO transformer in 3" Sched 80 PVC

It will be located on a stand alone power pedestal about 50-75 feet from each of the two structurs (house and storage).

I intend to use 1 lug to run a 4/0 AL to the house to a 66 space panel with a 200A main breaker.
I intend to use 1 lug to run a 4/0 AL to the attached garage to a 42 space panel with a 200A main breaker.
The last lug will go to a 30 space outdoor panel with a 200A breaker on the power pedestal, and then use a 200A breaker and 4/0 AL to go to the cold storage building.

(Why 4/0 to cold storage?  I'll just buy a 500' roll of 4/0 4/0 4/0 2/0 and sell the remnant.  I think it'll just be easier to keep it consistent, and there's a good price break for just getting a 500' roll....)

I understand I will need 2 grounding electrodes at the power pedestal and 2 at each of the sub panel locations.  In the house and attached garages I'll do an UFER in addition to a second ground rod installed below the concrete.

Questions:
Since the power pedestal will be within visual site of the house and storage building, will I need additional 200A disconnects at the 3 entrance points?

The 400A meter/main only has 3 lugs for the neutral conductor.  They didn't allow for 3 lugs to attach the 3 grounded conductors as required by 250.24. I called and asked the panel manufacturer about complaince with 250.24 and they said they don't view the attached 400A breaker as the first means of disconnect, and only 3 wires are needed to each of the 3 sub panels which is why they only provided 3 neutral lugs.  That seems to contradict what I read everywhere else.  This would mean there would be 3 bonding points - 1 at each sub panel.   Thoughts on this?

Is 4/0 big enough for 320A continuous when run in parallel in a single conduit, or should I up this to 250?  The line side of the meter lugs can handle up to dual 300 wire size.  If I up to 300, then I'd have to go to 3 1/2 conduit as well.

Any other considerations?

Thank you for any thoughts?

Comment: Speaking from a cold climate, in-floor resistance heat and propane heat are not cost-competitive (running cost) with either cold climate or ground-source heat pumps.  Since you're here before the build, remember the Ufer grounds in the footings of all the buildings. In many cases that can be the only ground (they are that good.) Some other folks can get you more specific details if you specify your utility-to-be.

Comment: The floor heat will be tubes in concrete connected to a boiler.  Right now electric seems to be significantly cheaper than propane.  We do need to look at ground-source heat pumps.  We all know that energy isn't going to get any cheaper.  I have so much left to research not sure how I'm going to be ready to build in 12-18 months.

Comment: @Blaster556 -- there are air-to-water reverse cycle chillers (SpacePak, Chiltrix, and so on) out there that can drive in-floor radiant heat systems (and even use them to provide radiant *cooling* in summer provided you have a ventilating dehumidifier or ERV that can control the latent loads sufficiently)

Comment: @Blaster556 -- also, who's your POCO, and what's the distance from the POCO transformer (pad or pole) to your power pedestal?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel It's a small rural electric Co-Op.  They provide no guidance whatsoever on meter issues.  As compared to say Xcel Energy which has a 200 page document!  All they want is a singe phase 4 jaw meter, ringless prefered.  Other than that, anything goes they say.  Of course, they won't put that in writing...

Comment: @Blaster556 -- noted on the metering guidance (or lack thereof) although we have what we need to know for this for the most part.  Do you know how far it is from the POCO transformer to your proposed disconnect location? Also, what's the 99% winter design temp for where you're at? (that latter figure tells us just how cold "cold" is for you, and has a large influence on what I'll recommend for HVAC as propane sure isn't cheap!)